# Можно ли внутри IIFE создать функцию которая получила бы доступ к this этой самой IIFE?

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict';
var s = 1;
(function() {
        var s = 2;
        (function() {
                var s = 3;
                alert(this.s);

                // Ошибка т.к. this - undefined в strict mode
                // Если без strict mode то 1, т.к. this глобальный объект
                // А как мне 2 получить?

        })();
})();
```

Comment: передать как параметр очевидно `(function(outerVariableS) { ...... })(s);`

Comment: а как ты думаешь, какой _this_ у верхней функции???

Comment: контекст и область видимости это разные вещи.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Передать переменную в качестве параметра не выход, т.к. я хочу из вложенной функции создавать переменные в контексте первой через `this`

Comment: @zb' Да, согласен. Неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Я имел ввиду возможность получения доступа к записи переменных во внешней области видимости.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. делая `var s = 2;` ты **не добавляешь** переменную в *this*, следовательно, твоя попытка обратиться к этой переменной как *this.s* - в корне не верна.
2. В твоем примере у обеих функций будет один и тот же *this*, *undefined* в *strict mode* и глобальный объект в противном случае.
3. В приведенном примере в каждой функции есть *своя* переменная *s* и ни одна из функций не может получить напрямую доступ к переменной определенной в другой функции. Единственный вариант - передавать нужные переменные как параметр.

Если же ты хочешь использовать *this*, то тебе не подойдет IIFE.

Тебе нужно либо использовать обычную функцию, в которой передавать нужные параметры, либо использовать [*call*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) для установки нужного контекста во внутренней функции.

```js
'use strict';
var s = 1;
(function() {
  var s = 2;
  (function() {
    var s = 3;
    console.log(this.s);
  }).call({s});
})();
```

Comment: Да я `this` как пример привёл. Я знал что через него доступ получить нельзя, собственно об этом и написал.

Comment: @Khipster, в любом случае - ответ: никак